# Color ramp node resets one color when rendering

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, color

I am using a color ramp node to set the base colors for a vertex group. It works fine, but I have one problem with the selected colors.

As you can see in my screenshot, I have selected purple, blue, pink and white colors in my color ramp, but **as soon as I press render image**, the first color suddenly changes to black.

Here is the color ramp node before I start rendering:

[image: Color ramp node before rendering]

As soon as I start rendering it changes to this:

[image: Color ramp node after rendering]

I am using the cycles rendering engine.

**Question: Why does this happen? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?**

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You put a keyframe on the color, that's why it has that yellow frame. Click on it with right mouse button and choose "Clear Keyframes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@FFeller](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/46481/ffeller)'s comment was completely right!

Somehow, a key frame was created on that first color. After deleting it (right mouse button click on the color), the original color is used and it doesn't turn black on rendering.

[image]